# Call function from as a string in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have this array of object:

```
let choices = [
    {title: 'Single Card Payment', func: 'singleCard'},
    {title: 'Monthly Card Payment', func: 'monthlyCard' },
    {title: 'Monthly Direct Debit Payment', func: 'monthlyDD'}
]
```

I'm looping through with it and I would like to call functions with the value of the func, like this **(which is obviously wrong)**

```
for(choice for choices) {
    choice.func('some', 'params');
}
```

Comment: Use [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) for arrays not [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). More info in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Assuming you have `singleCard` defined in your current scope, changing `func: 'singleCard'` to `func: singleCard` etc. so that it holds a reference to your function should work

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object with methods. Like below

```js
const funcs = {
    singleCard: () => { console.log('single card called ')}
}
```

And then call like this

```js
for (i in choices) {
    funcs[choices[i].func]()
}
```

Comment: you can add more methods in `funcs` object above.

Answer (score -3):

using **evil** function:

```
    let choices = [
    {title: 'Single Card Payment', func: 'singleCard'},
    {title: 'Monthly Card Payment', func: 'monthlyCard' },
    {title: 'Monthly Direct Debit Payment', func: 'monthlyDD'}
]
for(i in choices) {
    eval(choices[i].func)('some', 'params');
}
```

edit: it's eval guys not evil. 0K.

Comment: [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Comment: that's why i call that evil

Comment: And that's why it should be avoided